# the value does not change while running the code

Tags: html, count, undefined, textarea, freemarker

I have written this to Count the number of the spaces in the text area in html and it was working very good but after I imported this in intellj and turn it from .htm to .ftl ( it is required from the prof in ftl (Freimarker template) ) it tells me there is a problem and the remaining is unfined. a foto is attached . thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9TRg.jpg)

Comment: please provide the code/[mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.